# Why Java repaint() method isnt repainting? My code is proper

Tags: java, swing, awt

I extracted this code from 2008 Java Book (Java Heads First). And extracted also other code in the same time. One is working, other is not. Both use repaint() method in animation. I compared both codes very very carefully and they are the same! I can't tell why this code isnt repainting itself... It repaints only if I minimise and maximalise, but not during for loop. I will show you the code that is NOT working. Thanks for any input.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ProstaAnimacja {

  int x = 70;
  int y = 70;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProstaAnimacja gui = new ProstaAnimacja();
    gui.doRoboty();
  }

  public void doRoboty() {
    JFrame ramka = new JFrame();
    ramka.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MojPanelRysunkowy panel = new MojPanelRysunkowy();

    ramka.getContentPane().add(panel);
    ramka.setSize(300,300);
    ramka.setVisible(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 130; i++) {
      x++;
      y++;

      panel.repaint();

      try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (Exception ex) { }
    } 
  } // koniec doRoboty()

  public class MojPanelRysunkowy extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(Color.green);
      g.fillOval(x,y,40,40);
    }
  } // koniec klasy wewnÄ™trznej

} // koniec klasy zewnÄ™trznej
```

Comment: The code breaks Swing threading rules. Use a Swing Timer.

Comment: This may be not related to your problem, but `paintComponent` should always invoke its `super.paintComponent(g)` to ensure printing default elements related to panel so you wouldn't need to care about them (like borders, background).

Comment: And hint: it is 2017 now. Simply throw away your 9 year old book and either buy a new one or follow recent, up to date tutorials. Oracle has extensive material both for swing and javafx: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: @Pshemo Ohh actually that solved the issue lol. I dont knwo why because other code doesnt have super.paintComponent(g) but other code was working. Well I used your super and now it repaints. thank you <3

Comment: @GhostCat Im aware its very outdated but I couldnt find anything up to date. I didnt even know about JavaFX but I guess I should switch to it. Is there anything you would recommend for reading except Java Docs?

Comment: @GhostCat Im affraid Oracle Tutorials are not available in my language. If I read in english then I dont understand every second word because they tend to use professional terms.

Comment: Well, that is a problem then. I would suggest to A) do some web search then ... and B) look out for newer books in your language.

Comment: @GhostCat Swing doesn't change a lot(close to nothing) in the last 9 years...

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Well. But many things that you back then solved using inner classes would be lambdas and method references in todays world. So although the components are pretty much the same, you can (and should) do many things in a different way in 2017.

Comment: @GhostCat I 100% agree with you, but as you can see OP is probably beginnig with Swing, lambas could be deadly for Him at this point :D

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Yes. So he first learns how to write tedious anonymous inner classes, and each time he has a question about it, he finds at least one SO answer that says "and this is how you do it with lambdas" ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat I will then follow official Oracle tutorials regarding Java. They seem much better option because they are up to date. Hopefully I won't struggle with the language (at least not that much). Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed call to `super.paintComponent(Graphics g)` that's why :) Fixed implementation:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ProstaAnimacja {

  int x = 70;
  int y = 70;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProstaAnimacja gui = new ProstaAnimacja();
    gui.doRoboty();
  }

  public void doRoboty() {
    JFrame ramka = new JFrame();
    ramka.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MojPanelRysunkowy panel = new MojPanelRysunkowy();

    ramka.getContentPane().add(panel);
    ramka.setSize(300,300);
    ramka.setVisible(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 130; i++) {
      x++;
      y++;

      panel.repaint();

      try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (Exception ex) { }
    } 
  } // koniec doRoboty()

  public class MojPanelRysunkowy extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      //The fix is in the next line - it clears the background 
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.green);
      g.fillOval(x,y,40,40);
    }
  } // koniec klasy wewnÄ™trznej

} // koniec klasy zewnÄ™trznej
```